# Integral related to modified Bessel Function

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for a closed form solution for the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ik(x-\sin x)} \ dx,$$

where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. The solution is related to the modified Bessel function of the first kind, but finding the exact functional form is outside of my reach.

Any tips are appreciated,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 
$$
J_k(k).
$$ 
You can see that by entering $n=k$ and $t=k$ in the integral representation
$$
J_n(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(nx-t\sin x)}\,dx.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how I missed this definition. No dinner for me tonight.